# How to evaluate this weird delta-function like sum

Tags: many-body, correlation-functions, bosons

In the process of computing the two-point function for a free boson system, I have been led to the following sum that I'm not sure how to evaluate:

$$\sum_{\vec{k}}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\frac{\vec{k}^{2}}{2m}t})$$

The sum is naturally over the Brillouin zone, and $\vec{x},t$ are real constants. What does this object look like? I thought about turning this into an integral and completing the square, but this calculation is in $d$-dimensions and this doesn't seem to make things make easier. This is somewhat close to a delta function sum but not quite - does anyone know what this object becomes?

I can provide more info on my overall calculation but I think I have reduced it to the problem of evaluating this sum.

Comment: What is the domain? It is not periodic w.r.t. 2 pi

Answer (score 1):

This object is a certain generalization of [$\theta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), and a particular kind of [modular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form). Are these links solve your problem?

Comment: I think this is helpful - at least I now have some idea of what this thing could be. Though that doesn't answer why this should show up in such a simple calculation... but many thanks!